# How do I edit my lists on twitter.com?

Tags: twitter

Clearly I did this before because I have lists showing up when I go to twitter.com, but I can't figure out how to edit them now (i.e. move people  / add people / delete people from the lists).

Comment: Have added bounty as the accepted answer doesnt appear to work anymore. I would like to remove someone I'm no longer following from a list. Or remove anyone from the list.

Comment: @Paul an answer has been added with the appropriate steps to remove someone from a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the new steps with screenshots

1. Go to https://twitter.com
2. Click on lists
   [image: Lists link]
3. Choose a list and select View list page
   [image: List page]
4. Click "Following" on the list page
   [image: Following link on the Twitter list Page]
5. Select the person icon next to the user you want to edit
   [image: Edit a person on a list]
6. Then decide whether you want to remove or add a person to the list

Alternatively, you can go the user's page and decide and remove that person from there

[image: Profile list edit]

**Note**

The UI ideally should hint that "Add to List" also includes remove from list.

Comment: thanks, thats it. silly me for not clicking on "Add to list" when I want to remove from list!

Answer (score 2):

Click on any of your twitter lists on the left side of your home feed., click on the view the list page link. Click on following to delete people from your list.

To add: Go to any person's page and click on the menu on the left and add to any of your lists

Comment: Have tried to do this without success, I think Twitter UI has changed since Aug 2010